# How combine these two with each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, python-import

I made this 2 pack of codes but I do not know how I can put my password on my folder with `os` library. it will be nice if somebody can help me

```
import random

small = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
capital = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbers = "123456789"
symbol = "[] { } () : ; @ $ &"
password = small + capital + numbers + symbol
lenght = 15
password = "".join(random.sample(password , lenght))
print(password)
```

---

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\Chris\\Python"
os.chdir(path)
files = "new file"
for i in range (1,11):
    files = "new file" + str(i)
    os.makedirs(files)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `putting password on folder`? Do you want to make a secure folder that requires you to enter a password whenever you want to open it?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani yes I am trying to do the same  . I want to secure my folder with the other password that I made on first place